# Highcharts - IE8 not rendering chart correctly

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

We have a chart that is rendering incorrectly in IE8.  We just updated the Highcharts.js file yesterday with the latest version as we were receiving a script error on "d.join".  Now we don't get any script error and our page continues to load properly, a step in the right direction, however the chart is missing the axis and plot lines and the coloring.

Here is what the chart looks like in Chrome/IE10/IE9:

[image: Chrome]

and in IE 8:

[image: Internet Explorer]

Please help me figure this out.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery and have you recently updated that to version 2? If so then that'll be where your problem lies.

Comment: We have identified the latest update to Telerik controls or the concurrent update to JQuery as responsible for this.  I will post when we figure it out as I am sure many of your users are using the same technologies.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the help.  We just realized that had happened.  Unfortunately, we rely heavily on JQuery and want to keep the latest version.  Will there be a fix to this soon?

Comment: jQuery v2 drops support for ie8 and below. This is intentional so there will be no fix. Your best bet is to downgrade to the latest 1.x version of jQuery. Alternatively you could drop support for ie8!

Comment: I would love to drop support for IE8!  Unfortunately, a lot of our customers use it still so we have to give them some time.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is due to upgrading to jQuery 2.x. jQuery has intentionally dropped support for Internet Explorer 8 and below. See http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Your solution would be to either

1. Downgrade to jQuery 1.x
2. Drop your support for Internet Explorer 8

Comment: Digging into this further, we were using JQuery 1.9.X, not 2.0, so it should still be working, correct?  When we roll back to 1.7.2 it begins working again.   Any ideas?

Comment: No javascript errors.  We are getting further as it works fine on one computer and not on another.  Is there some IE 8 security setting that could cause this perhaps?

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache/history. Aside from that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: This is the line of code, from the render function, that was messing up even though we weren't running in Quirks mode:

`doAnimation = animation && !!series.animate && 
    chart.renderer.isSVG, // this animation doesn't work in IE8 quirks when the group div is hidden,
    // and looks bad in other oldIE`

To fix, I had Reset Internet Explorer.  I don't think we are going to investigate further into which setting was causing this unless we have a client that experiences the same issue.  However, if anyone knows the answer, please post! Thanks!